# How to Rotate a GameObject around its center, from script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After countless searches, I don't understand how this is possible, in the Unity editor window, this is very easy.

How do you Rotate an object, that exists at any point in the world, where it perfectly rotates around it's own center point?

I don't want to add a "parent" gameobject, and I don't want to necessarily rely on the object's MeshRenderer.  (due to mismatching naming conventions)

Here is the latest code I have tried.  (I had the most success with this)

```
public float deg = 0;
public GameObject go;
public Vector3 center;
public Rigidbody rb;

void Start ()
{
    deg = 0;
    go = this.gameObject;

    rb = go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    center = go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    deg += 1f;

    if (deg >= 360f) deg = 0;


    Vector3 cen = go.transform.position; // + center;

    go.transform.RotateAround(cen, Vector3.up, deg);


}
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that either it rotates around the corner of the object, or it rotates around the center, but moves the object all over the screen.  In the code revision above, it rotates around the corner.

Comment: What is the behavior that you are seeing when you rotate in code now? Is the object not rotating at all? It is rotating around a different point than expected?

Comment: Also, please post the code you have tried so far. [mcve]

Comment: There are two rotation settings, pivot and 'center.' Center involves computing the geometric center of all involved points. For a single mesh, this is inside the mesh. Doing this yourself is hard. If the pivot of your mesh is not inside the mesh, you should recenter it. Either by using a dummy parent or fixing it in your 3D modeling program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `center = go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center;` gives you the center's position **in local space** (the center's position relative to `go`'s position and rotation), but if you're using `RotateAround`, the first argument needs to be **in global space** (the center's position relative to the origin point with no rotation).

So, to fix the problem, we need to convert from local space to global space. We can use [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) to do this:

```
public float deg = 2f;
public GameObject go;
public Vector3 cenLocal;
public Rigidbody rb;

void Start ()
{
    go = this.gameObject;

    rb = go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    cenLocal = go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center; // Center (local space)
}


private void FixedUpdate()
{    
    Vector3 cenGlobal = go.transform.TransformPoint(cenLocal); // Center (global space)

    go.transform.RotateAround(cenGlobal , Vector3.up, deg);
}
```

As an aside, you may already know this, but if `go == this.gameObject` always, you can just use `transform.xyz` instead of `go.transform.xyz`. Simply using `transform` is the more conventional way of referring to `this.gameObject.transform`.

Comment: Stunningly Beautiful!  Works like an absolute charm!  Thank you SO much!